# Android-two threads changing the ui

Tags: android

I have a UI with buttons. This thread takes input from the user and does a particular task. Now, I want the background of one button(generated randomly) to change periodically(say, every 30s), but i want the main thread to continue taking input. I m not able to interleave the threads in exactly this way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

pleas extend the Hanlder class and override the handle message . create the instance of it in on create of activity and post the message to it and hanlder will change the button background .please keep the reference of drawable in string array and take a integer that will change the image resource ........